# Jsoup's select return set instead of array

Tags: java, select, jsoup

I need to select all elements by class. But select returns only unique elements.
For example, i have two same elements 1 and i want to get both elements and change them. But changing only first element.
How can I get array of elements instead of set?

Detailed example:

```
String str = "<span class="episode-number">1</span><span class="episode-number">1</span>";
Elements el = Jsoup.parse(str);
for(Element e: el.select(".episode-number")
    e.wrap("<b></b>");
```

This snippet convert str to

```
"<b><span class="episode-number">1</span></b>
<span class="episode-number">1</span>"
```

Instead

```
"<b><span class="episode-number">1</span></b> 
<b><span class="episode-number">1</span></b>"
```

Comment: Please share the relevant code.

Comment: What specific method are you invoking, in which version?

Comment: Did my answer solve your problem? If yes you should accept it so the thread can be considered closed. If not please provide feedback so I can update my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your example doesn't compile.

1. This is wrong, since the double quotes of the classes are not escaped.

`String str = "<span class="episode-number">1</span><span class="episode-number">1</span>";`

2. This is wrong since `Jsoup.parse` returns a `Document` object.

`Elements el = Jsoup.parse(str);`

3. A parenthesis is missing in for loop.

The below works as expected

```
String str = "<span class=\"episode-number\">1</span><span class=\"episode-number\">1</span>";
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(str);
for(Element e: doc.select(".episode-number"))
    e.wrap("<b></b>");

System.out.println(doc);
```

**Ouput**

```
<html>
 <head></head>
 <body>
  <b><span class="episode-number">1</span></b>
  <b><span class="episode-number">1</span></b>
 </body>
</html>
```